# Dúvida em AngularJS! (Factory, Controller, View) Porque 'identity' não é atualizado na VIEW?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-services, angularjs-factorys

Galera estou com uma dúvida em AngularJS!

O código fonte está em https://plnkr.co/edit/BoIr6nFCa8ST5ekT3DZO

Na factory tenho uma propriedade com o nome `identity`, que é espelhada para a controller e apresentada na view. Ao adicionar uma nova mensagem essa propriedade é incrementada corretamente, o problema é que ela não é atualizada na view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está preservando um valor, não o objeto. *messages* e *identity* são propriedades do serviço *messageService*. A sequência no seu código é a seguinte:

- *messageService* é inicializado. Propriedade *identity* recebe o valor **literal** 0.
- variável local do *controller* recebe o valor **literal** presente na propriedade messageService.identity (0), na prática copiando o valor.
- messageService.identity é atualizada, porém como o valor é literal e não uma referência, variáveis locais permanecem intocadas.

Eu alterei seu código para preservar a instância, assim:

```
vm1.ms = messageService;
```

Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('messageService', function() {
  var messenger = {
    messages: [],
    identity: 0,
    addMessage: function(text, caller) {

      this.identity += 1;
      var id = this.identity,
        message = {
          text: caller + ": " + text + ": " + id,
          id: id
        };

      this.messages.push(message);
    }
  };

  return messenger;
});

app.controller('Controller1', function(messageService) {
  var vm1 = this;
  vm1.ms = messageService; // ALTERAÇÃO
  vm1.post = {
    text: ''
  };

  vm1.postMessage = function() {
    messageService.addMessage(vm1.text, "controller 1");
    vm1.text = '';
  };

});



app.controller('Controller2', function($scope, messageService) {
  var vm2 = this;
  vm2.ms = messageService; // ALTERAÇÃO
  vm2.post = {
    text: ''
  };

  vm2.postMessage = function() {
    messageService.addMessage(vm2.text, "controller 2");
    vm2.text = '';
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as vm1">
      <h1>Controller 1 - {{vm1.ms.identity}}</h1>
      <ul ng-repeat="msg1 in vm1.ms.messages">
        <li>{{msg1.text}}</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        Controller 1 Message: <input type="text" ng-model="vm1.text">
        <button ng-click="vm1.postMessage()">Post</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div ng-controller="Controller2 as vm2">
      <h1>Controller 2 - {{vm2.ms.identity}}</h1>
      <ul ng-repeat="msg2 in vm2.ms.messages">
        <li>{{msg2.text}}</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        Controller 2 Message: <input type="text" ng-model="vm2.text">
        <button ng-click="vm2.postMessage()">Post</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ou então eu encapsulo o `identity` em um objeto específico, certo? Não estou muito contente com o fato de ter que expor todo o service em uma variável do controller. Esse é a melhor prática para este caso?

Comment: @LucasBoeingScarduelli Exato, você pode encapsular as propriedades desejadas em um objeto.